# How to config apache proxy to serve hexo's static file

Tags: apache, hexo

I use apache proxy to get my hexo blog site.

```
ProxyPass /blog http://127.0.0.1:4000/
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://127.0.0.1:4000/
```

But apache can not serve hexo static files(css,js,images) properly.
I have to Rewrite the static file url like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/js/(.+)$ /blog/js/$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^/css/(.+)$ /blog/css/$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^/fancybox/(.+)$ /blog/fancybox/$1 [R]
```

When i change a theme, i have to rewrite those rewriterules.
Is there a simple way to solve this?.